# How to Get Month Short Name from Yearmonth Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a column in SQL Server named yearmonth e.g. 201906. I want to show the monthname from that column, but can't find a way to show it.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: from your question, It seems l be sql-server.  so I remove `mysql` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use let your column be a good date format string, then use `CAST` with `Format` function.

```
select FORMAT(CAST('201906' + '01' AS DATE), 'MMMM')
```

or `DATENAME` function.

```
select DATENAME(month,CAST('201906' + '01' AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the short month name, so you need to take only the left 3 characters of the Month Name.
you can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(month,CAST(yearmonth + '01' AS DATE)), 3) FROM MyTable
```